# How to install Ubuntu Server over Ubuntu Desktop on my mac?

Tags: server

I currently am running Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 on my macbook. I have a cd of Ubuntu Server 12.04 and want to wipe my mac and install Ubuntu server but have not been able to find any information about how to do this on a mac already running Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Put the disk in the computer, run the disk, go through the install steps until you get to disk partitioning then make sure you have the install delete the ubuntu (ext3 or ext4) and swap partitions (if you don't care about osx then wipe that to) then continue as usual. Frankly if you don't care for anything on that drive you have really don't have to do anything beyond clicking next a few times.

Comment: osX is already wiped of the computer, I currently am only running Ubuntu 12.04 on my MacBook. I know when there was osX on the computer I just held alt/option when it booted to select the boot disk but it isn't working without osX on the machine!

Comment: @StuartYamartino No alt, I believe it's just option beyond that hard to say perhaps its a UEFI issue...